# Why the irrelevant code made a difference?

Tags: python, windows, winapi, ctypes

I am thinking to make a progress bar with python in terminal. First, I have to get the width(columns) of terminal window. In python 2.7, there is no standard library can do this on Windows. I know maybe I have to call Windows Console API manually.

According to MSDN and Python Documentation, I wrote the following code:

```python
import ctypes
import ctypes.wintypes

class CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('dwSize', ctypes.wintypes._COORD),
        ('dwCursorPosition', ctypes.wintypes._COORD),
        ('wAttributes', ctypes.c_ushort),
        ('srWindow', ctypes.wintypes._SMALL_RECT),
        ('dwMaximumWindowSize', ctypes.wintypes._COORD)
    ]
hstd = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetStdHandle(ctypes.c_ulong(-11)) # STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11
print hstd
csbi = CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO()
print ctypes.sizeof(csbi) # <---------------
ret = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(ctypes.c_ulong(hstd), csbi)
print ret
print csbi.dwSize.X
```

It works fine. I set about deleting some `print` in code. But after that, it doesn't work! `GetLastError` return 6 (Invalid Handle). After times of trying, I found that there must be SOMETHING at the pointed position of the code such as `print 'hello'`, `import sys` or `sys.stdout.flush()`. At first, I guess that maybe it need time to do something. So I tried to put `time.sleep(2)` at that position, but it still doesn't work.

But, if I do use `struct` instead of `ctypes.Structure`, there's no such problem.

```python
import ctypes
import struct

hstd = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetStdHandle(-11) # STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11
csbi = ctypes.create_string_buffer(22)
res = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hstd, csbi)
width, height, curx, cury, wattr, left, top, right, bottom, maxx, maxy = struct.unpack("hhhhHhhhhhh", csbi.raw)
print bufx
```

Is there any one can tell me why the irrelevant code made such a difference?

Comment: To use `GetLastError` reliably from Python, use `kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)` and then call `ctypes.get_last_error`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the struct by reference:

```
ret = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(
    ctypes.c_ulong(hstd), 
    ctypes.byref(csbi)
)
```

I would also recommend that you declare the `restype` for `GetStdHandle`. That will mean that your code is ready to run under a 64 bit process. I'd write it like this:

```
ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetStdHandle.restype = ctypes.wintypes.HANDLE
hstd = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetStdHandle(-11) # STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11
csbi = CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO()
ret = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(
    hstd, 
    ctypes.byref(csbi)
)
```

Actually, in my version of Python, your code reports a much more useful error. I see this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in 
    ret = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(ctypes.c_ulong(hstd), csbi)
ValueError: Procedure probably called with too many arguments (20 bytes in 
excess)
```

This is enough to make it clear that there is an binary mismatch at the interface between the Python code and the native code.

I suspect that if you get a more recent version of Python, you'd also benefit from this stack imbalance checking.

Comment: I have trid that. But if I use `ctypes.byref` (as what I did at first), I couldn't get right value whether I keep the pointed line.

Comment: @eryksun I'm not sure I follow your second comment. If I assign `HANDLE` to `GetStdHandle.restype` then `hstd` will be of type `HANDLE`. Then when I pass `hstd` to `GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo` doesn't that mean that ctypes will use the type of `hstd` to correctly marshal a pointer sized object even without an explicit `argtypes` specification.

Comment: @eryksun So, there's no possibility of 64 to 32 bit truncation on the return value, it just means that you don't end up with a pointer type. And then you may truncate when passing the handle as a parameter. Does this mean that that argtypes is required in my code above, to ensure that a 64 bit value is passed?

Comment: @eryksun Thank you very much. I've really learnt a lot about ctypes from you of late, I do appreciate it!

Comment: 2.7.5 links: [`GetResult`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ab05e7dd2788/Modules/_ctypes/callproc.c#l899) and [`getfunc`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ab05e7dd2788/Modules/_ctypes/cfield.c#l1580) for type 'P'.

Comment: I finally convert hstd to ctypes.wintypes.HANDLE instead of ulong and succeed. (I am working on 64-bit Windows.)