# Strange inconsistencies getting default console colors on Windows with Python

Tags: python, windows, console

I am trying to get the default console colors using Python on Windows 8, 64-bit:

```
class CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('dwSize', wintypes._COORD),
                ('dwCursorPosition', wintypes._COORD),
                ('wAttributes', c_ushort),
                ('srWindow', wintypes._SMALL_RECT),
                ('dwMaximumWindowSize', wintypes._COORD)]

...

def __init__(self):
        self.stdout_handle = windll.kernel32.GetStdHandle(-11) # STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
        print self.stdout_handle # 28

        csbi   = CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO()
        print sizeof(csbi) # 22
        retval = windll.kernel32.GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(self.stdout_handle, byref(csbi))
        print windll.kernel32.GetLastError()
        print csbi.wAttributes, " (%s)" % bin(csbi.wAttributes)

        if retval == 0:
            formatwinerror() # A helper function
```

Using the interactive interpreter (importing and creating the object), this fails using Python 2.7.5 with the last error code being 6 (invalid handle) and the attributes 0. If I run the same code Python 3.3.2, it works (error code 0 and attributes 0xf which are the default). Interestingly, if I use Python 2.7.5 and use the following code instead, it works:

```
import struct

...Same as before...

csbi = create_string_buffer(22)
retval = windll.kernel32.GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(self.stdout_handle, csbi)
width, height, curx, cury, wattr, left, top, right, bottom, maxx, maxy = struct.unpack("hhhhHhhhhhh", csbi.raw)

print wattr, " (%s)" % bin(wattr)

...Same as before...
```

For additional debugging, I copied the core of the calls into a separate script (also tried it inside a function outside the class) and now it runs perfectly on the command line for both versions. However, if I add this line before the call to GetStdHandle, the separate script fails for Python 2.7.5 (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17993814/why-the-irrelevant-code-made-a-difference)), but still fails using the interactive interpreter:

```
windll.kernel32.GetStdHandle.restype = wintypes.HANDLE
```

For Python 3.3.2, everything seems to work regardless. I been searched, reading, looking at other Python modules and reviewing my code all evening with no luck...What the hell is going on and what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had not considered what kind of architecture the Python interpreter was compiled on.

After adding the line `windll.kernel32.GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo.argtypes = [wintypes.HANDLE, ctypes.POINTER(CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO)]` to my code it works for all my interpreters. I still cannot explain why my Python 3.3.2 works (64-bit architecture), but I guess some Python 3.x changes are perhaps the cause.