# Console Screen Buffer Info shows incorrect X position

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes

I recently found a great short code [Why the irrelevant code made a difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17993814/why-the-irrelevant-code-made-a-difference) for obtaining console screen buffer info (which I include below) that replaces the huge code accompanying the standard 'CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO()' method (which I won't include here!)

```
import ctypes
import struct

print("xxx",end="") # I added this to show what the problem is

hstd = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetStdHandle(-11) # STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11
csbi = ctypes.create_string_buffer(22)
res = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hstd, csbi)
width, height, curx, cury, wattr, left, top, right, bottom, maxx, maxy = struct.unpack("hhhhHhhhhhh", csbi.raw)
# The following two lines are also added
print()  # To bring the cursor to next line for displaying infp
print(width, height, curx, cury, wattr, left, top, right, bottom, maxx, maxy) # Display what we got
```

Output:
80 250 0 7 7 0 0 79 24 80 43

This output is for Windows 10 MSDOS, with clearing the screen before running the code. However. 'curx' = 0 although it should be 3 (after printing "xxx"). The same phenomenon happens also with the 'CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO()' method. Any idea what is the problem?

Also, any suggestion for a method of obtaining current cursor position -- besides 'curses' library -- will be welcome!

Answer (score 2):

You need to flush the print buffer if you don't output a linefeed:

```
print("xxx",end="",flush=True)
```

Then I get the correct curx=3 with your code:

```
xxx
130 9999 3 0 14 0 0 129 75 130 76
```

BTW the original answer in the posted question is the "great" code.  The "bitness" of `HANDLE` can break your code, and not defining `.argtypes` as a "shortcut" is usually the cause of most `ctypes` problems.

Comment: Right. Forgot that! Thanks.